# combining n objects with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I'm not looking native javascript only. I'm open to jQuery and underscore.js as well. I've googled a bit and I found questions/answers only explaining how to combine two objects and not more.

There is .extend from jquery which can do that. I'm looking for something that combines n objects with different properties into single object.

I'm actually doing a `$('form').serializeArray()` and then I get array of objects from the form. Is there a way I can get a single object from a form? Or how to combine more objects with different properties into single object?

Comment: You have an array. $.extend is for objects. What exactly are you trying to do? submit multiple forms through 1 ajax request?

Comment: Can you give an example of the objects you're working with, and the expected output for those example objects?

Comment: he has `[{name: "inputname",value:"inputvalue"},...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a form to a json object use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186309/1183010).
quote from answer above:

> `serializeArray` already does exactly that, you just need to massage the
>   data into your required format:
>
> ```
> $.fn.serializeObject = function()
> {
>     var o = {};
>     var a = this.serializeArray();
>     $.each(a, function() {
>         if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
>             if (!o[this.name].push) {
>                 o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
>             }
>             o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
>         } else {
>             o[this.name] = this.value || '';
>         }
>     });
>     return o;
> };
> ```

To combine multiple objects use [underscore extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend):

```
_.extend({name: 'moe'}, {age: 50}, {test: "test"});
```

or [jQuery extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
$.extend({name: 'moe'}, {age: 50}, {test: "test"})
```